# ListBox и БД

Tags: delphi

Какие форматы читает ListBox ?

Может ли он читать xml/cds базы данных?
Хоть какую нибудь БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выполнить запрос, а потом пробегая результат запроса, записывать необходимые данные в ListBox

Answer (score 0):

Класс TListBox никак не связан с базой данных и тем более с xml. Формирование списка целиком лежит на разработчике